# Disable Jqgrid column on clicking on check box (out side jqgrid)

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I want to disable jqgrid column based on click.

i have a jqgrid and a check box out side from jqgrid when i check the check box particular column should be in disable mode.

This is not for particular  row it is for all the row ,if i check the check box then particular column should be in disable mode

Comment: What you mean under "Disable Jqgrid column" or "column should be in disable mode"? The text displayed in the column could not be disabled.  Do you use formaters (like `formatter: "checkbox"`) which includes `<input>` or other elements which really can be enabled or disabled? Probably you mean disabling of editing of some column? In any way you should change the text of your question to clear the requirements or the problem which you have.

Comment: i know i can use formateer but i already written the code,i dont want to replace it ,look if i checked the check box then in inline edit mode the partitular column should not be in edit mode it should be in disable state show that user not able to select the value or not  enter the value to that text box.

Comment: You should describe more clear what you want and what you do. You should include code fragment which demonstrates what you do currently. For example how the column which you want to "disable" is defined in `colModel`? You write about the usage of inline edit mode, but it could be done in different ways: direct call of `editRow`, usage of `formatter: "actions"`, usage of `inlineNav`. The solution of the problem can be *different* depend on what kind of inline editing you use.

Comment: Ok i got it i use Formatter for this problem solve......thanks